# Check for any type of audio playing on page

Tags: javascript, audio, iframe, browser

Is it possible to check if the current window is playing any type of audio using javascript?

[image]

I have an embedded iframe that plays sound but due to cross-domain script restrictions I cannot check the state of the element using traditional methods to find out if it is playing audio.

Is there a document or window property I could access like `window.audio` or `window.sound` that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle example?

Comment: Sure. https://jsfiddle.net/7m83gxet/